# Why the image on hard disk getting smaller and some distortion when it show on pictureBox?

Tags: c#

My pictureBox1 is set to StretchImage and the size of the pictureBox1 is:

656,422

Now when i extract an image to the hard disk after rotated it by 270 degrees im getting this result:

[image]

When i load the image to the pictureBox1 run my application the image looks like this:

[image]

[image]

If i set the pictureBox1 SizeMode to Normal i see then only part of the image only the top of it. Is there anything to do ? Or i must make the pictureBox1 size larger or make the image on hard disk size smaller ?

After using PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom im getting this:

The last most bottom image. The question is if i should leave it like that or somehow to cut the pictureBox borders to the left and right so i will have only the image it self ? Is there any way to make that the pictureBox will automatic cut what is needed so it will left with the image it self depending on the image size ?

Sinze im using Zoom each image leave a diffrenet amount of space in the pictureBox.

Comment: If you make the BackColor of the PictureBox the same as the background color of the parent then you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Using the Zoom value causes the image to be stretched or shrunk to fit the PictureBox; however, the aspect ratio in the original is maintained.

For more information:
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx)

***EDIT:***

Or you can try this:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
```

The PictureBox is sized equal to the size of the image that it contains.

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx)